# Different page layout required for front matter and body matter

Tags: margins

As per my requirement I want different text width and margin for single book. Please suggest me how to fix this. Here my code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\def\frontmatter{\setlength{\textwidth}{117mm}
\setlength\textwidth{117mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin   {19mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin  {19mm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-1in}
}


\def\mainmatter{\setlength\textwidth{122mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin   {19mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin  {14mm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-1in}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter{FM title}
On the Insert tab, the galleries $\hypint$  include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document. You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers, footers, lists, cover pages, and other document building blocks. When you create pictures, charts, or diagrams, they also coordinate with your current document look. You can easily change the formatting of selected text in the document text by choosing a look for the selected text from the Quick Styles gallery on the Home tab. You can also for
mat text directly by using the other controls on the Home tab.

\mainmatter
\chapter{FM title}
On the Insert tab, the galleries $\hypint$  include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document. You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers, footers, lists, cover pages, and other document building blocks. When you create pictures, charts, or diagrams, they also coordinate with your current document look. You can easily change the formatting of selected text in the document text by choosing a look for the selected text from the Quick Styles gallery on the Home tab. You can also for
mat text directly by using the other controls on the Home tab.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us the size of the sheets of paper you're working with? Is it maybe `A5`? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the `geometry` package on the following way:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[hmargin={19mm,14mm},
            vmargin=1in]{geometry}% setting for maintmater

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\newgeometry{hmargin=19mm} % change to settings for frontmater
\chapter{FM title}
On the Insert tab, the galleries $yyy$  include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document. You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers, footers, lists, cover pages, and other document building blocks. When you create pictures, charts, or diagrams, they also coordinate with your current document look. You can easily change the formatting of selected text in the document text by choosing a look for the selected text from the Quick Styles gallery on the Home tab. You can also for
mat text directly by using the other controls on the Home tab.

\mainmatter
\restoregeometry   % restore to setting for mainmater
\chapter{FM title}
On the Insert tab, the galleries $xxx$  include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document. You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers, footers, lists, cover pages, and other document building blocks. When you create pictures, charts, or diagrams, they also coordinate with your current document look. You can easily change the formatting of selected text in the document text by choosing a look for the selected text from the Quick Styles gallery on the Home tab. You can also for
mat text directly by using the other controls on the Home tab.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Zarko for your answer, it's really fulfill my requirement